# Scratch text editor - Is it possible to install it on LinuxMint 17.1 (Rebecca)?

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, editors

I like what I see about Scratch text editor and would like to try it out on my LinuxMint 17.1 installation. I have been trying to follow some of the instructions in a couple of forums (one of them here https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/574pub/cant_install_scratch_text_editor_on_linux_mint_18/) but haven't been able to install it on 17.1 of LinuxMint. I keep running into issues like:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     scratch-text-editor : Depends: libscratchcore0 (= 2.2.1~r1550-0+pkg81~ubuntu0.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libgranite3 (>= 0.3.0+) but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: libgtksourceview-3.0-1 (>= 3.14.3) but 3.10.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Has anyone tried installing this successfully on LinuxMint 17.1 and have it working? Is it even possible? I used elementaryos:stable PPA for trying this.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/641636/text-editor-scratch might help.

Comment: @wolf no, this is completely off topic on [ubuntu.se]. Please dont suggest other sites unless you are familiar with that site's scope. Watson, this question would be on topic on [su] and [unix.se]. However, if you do choose to post there, make sure you include the exact commands you ran that gave this error.

Comment: @terdon chill—I meant that the issue of installing dependencies is already covered in the aforementioned askubuntu question